# Как загружать данные до рендеринга React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Начинаю осваиваться с React и уже несколько недель безуспешно пытаюсь найти способ подгружать данные до перехода к компоненту. Что я подразумеваю:
*Клиент перешёл с одной страницы приложения на другую -> данные получаются в фоне (всё это время клиент видит старый роут, с которого происходил переход) -> осуществляется рендер компонента с уже загруженными данными*.
На просторах сети я находил `react-async-component`, но, насколько я понял, это не то. Также много читал про серверный рендеринг, но это также не то, что нужно.
Учусь работать со связкой React + Redux + React Router V4.

Можете подсказать как реализовать то, что я описал выше? В идеале, если имеются, ссылки на документации (можно даже англоязычные, не принципиально).
Я понимаю, что просить готовое решение - плохая практика и неуместна здесь, но я не вижу других вариантов решения своей проблемы. :(

Comment: Как мне кажется вы усложняете себе жизнь. Это нормальная практика отображать прелоадер вместо компонента, пока не придут нужные данные. Вы можете просто создать дополнительный экшн (к примеру isLoading) и диспатчить его, когда ваши данные придут (в другом экшене, к примеру getData). Затем в самом компоненте в зависимости от значения isLoading показывать либо прелоадер, либо компонент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил такой вариант:

Если вы пользуетесь `HashRouter`, то в `history` (устанавливается вместе с `react-router-dom`) есть функция `createHashHistory`, создаете файл (например `hashHistory.js`):

```
import { createHashHistory } from "history";
export const history = createHashHistory();
```

при нажатии на кнопку (ссылку) на другую страницу, вы вызываете экшн, внутри экшена у вас асинхронная функция для получения данных, тогда вы в блоке `then` можете сделать переход на другую страницу:

```
import {history} from 'путь к файлу hashHistory.js'

// функция (экшн) для получения данных
const fetchData = () => {
     fetch(......)
          .then(response => {
                // тут у вас уже получены данные
                history.push(ваша страница на которую нужен переход)
          })
}
```